# In MySQL 5, SELECT COUNT(1) FROM table_name is very slow

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL 5.0 database with a few tables containing over 50M rows. But how do I know this? By running "SELECT COUNT(1) FROM foo", of course. This query on one table containing 58.8M rows took **10 minutes** to complete!

```
mysql> SELECT COUNT(1) FROM large_table;
+----------+
| count(1) |
+----------+
| 58778494 | 
+----------+
1 row in set (10 min 23.88 sec)

mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT COUNT(1) FROM large_table;
+----+-------------+-------------------+-------+---------------+----------------------------------------+---------+------+-----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table             | type  | possible_keys | key                                    | key_len | ref  | rows      | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------------------+-------+---------------+----------------------------------------+---------+------+-----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | large_table       | index | NULL          | fk_large_table_other_table_id          | 5       | NULL | 167567567 | Using index | 
+----+-------------+-------------------+-------+---------------+----------------------------------------+---------+------+-----------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> DESC large_table;
+-------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field             | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment | 
| created_on        | datetime            | YES  |     | NULL    |                | 
| updated_on        | datetime            | YES  |     | NULL    |                | 
| other_table_id    | int(11)             | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                | 
| parent_id         | bigint(20) unsigned | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                | 
| name              | varchar(255)        | YES  |     | NULL    |                | 
| property_type     | varchar(64)         | YES  |     | NULL    |                | 
+-------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

All of the tables in question are InnoDB.

Any ideas why this is so slow, and how I can speed it up?

Comment: Maybe you should post the output of "SHOW CREATE TABLE" and give us a bit of background info on your problem domain?

Comment: Mark, the problem domain doesn't really matter in this case, as all I'm trying to do is count rows. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to have the result instantly and you don't care if it's 58.8M or 51.7M, you can find out the approximate number of rows by calling

```
show table status like 'large_table';
```

See the column `rows`
For more information about the result take a look at the manual at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-table-status.html

Comment: This info is also available in INFORMATION_SCHEMA. The result is "a bit random" though.

Comment: Approximations are find for my use case. I just need the info for scaling computations, which really only need to be accurate within an order of magnitude. Since I'm not adding or deleting an order of magnitude rows, I need not worry about slight fuzziness.

Answer (score 6):

Counting all the rows in a table is a very slow operation; you can't really speed it up, unless you are prepared to keep a count somewhere else (and of course, that can become out of sync).

People who are used to MyISAM tend to think that they get count(*) "for free", but it's not really. MyISAM cheats by not having MVCC, which makes it fairly easy.

The query you're showing is doing a full index scan of a not-null index, which is generally the fastest way of counting the rows in an innodb table.

It is difficult to guess from the information you've given, what your application is, but in general, it's ok for users (etc) to see close approximations of the number of rows in large tables.

Comment: Some explanation here: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/12/01/count-for-innodb-tables/

Answer (score -2):

`select count(id) from large_table` will surely run faster

Comment: What makes you think that? Doing a PK index scan on InnoDB is worse than doing a secondary index scan in general (because the data are clustered, so the entries are usually bigger, hence fewer per page, hence more IO ops.)

Comment: COUNT(id) can never be faster than COUNT(1). Whenever you count row items and use * or a column name, an internal mechanism will check for the first non-NULL column in a row (when using COUNT(*)) or check the column specified in parentheses (when using COUNT(id)) That mechanism is bypassed by using COUNT(1) since 1 is a scalar number that evaluates the same always and thus the table columns in a row is never loaded and examined. I learned this from my Oracle Developer Days when I read about this on page 78 of Oracle8i Cert Study Guide book. As @MarkR started before, MVCC just gets in the way.

Comment: COUNT(some_non_null_column) should be the same as COUNT(1) or indeed, COUNT(*) anyway. If the optimiser treats them differently, it is broken.

Comment: Also notice from the EXPLAIN plan that the query optimizer decided to use the clustered index even though the query chose no columns.